# JavaScript replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, replace

```
function areaMe(area) {
    var barea = $('#barea').val();
    if (barea.indexOf(area) != -1) {
        alert ("..." + barea + "..." + area + "...");
        barea.replace(area, "cu"); // Remove
        alert ("..." + barea + "..." + area + "...");
    }
    else {
        barea += area + ' '; // Include.
    }
    $('#barea').val(barea);
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
barea = barea.replace(area, "cu")
```

You need to assign it since `String.prototype.replace` isn't a mutator method.

Comment: Why doesn't the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) mention this?

Comment: o gosh thanks hehehe

Answer (score 9):

You need to assign the replaced value back to your variable:

```
barea = barea.replace(area, "cu");
```

Answer (score 0):

> barea = barea.replace(area, "cu")