# Replace function showing undefined in the console

Tags: javascript, html, input, replace, undefined

So, I was trying to create e encryption app, the app should take the value of the input and use the replace function to change the letters to the words that I specified in the function trocaLetras, but it just returns undefined in the console log.

This is my code:

```js
var botaoCriptografar = document.querySelector('#criptografar');

function trocaLetras(conteudoInput) {
    conteudoInput.replace(/a/g, 'ai');
    conteudoInput.replace(/e/g, 'enter');
    conteudoInput.replace(/i/g, 'imes');
    conteudoInput.replace(/o/g, 'ober');
    conteudoInput.replace(/u/g, 'ufat');
}

botaoCriptografar.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var texto = document.querySelector('#texto-para-coleta').value;
    var textoAtualizado = trocaLetras(texto);
    console.log(textoAtualizado);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="texto-para-coleta"></textarea>
<button id="criptografar">Criptografar</button>
```

Comment: What did you expect, the function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: @mplungjan they are _Java_ questions.

Comment: [JS dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231644/js-replace-not-working-on-string), and [another JS dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891052/javascript-replace-doesnt-work), and [another JS dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825984/replace-javascript-not-working), and a [chaining JS dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` function will actually not change the value in the variable, but instead returns a string with the replaced characters. So you must chain  multiple calls of `replace`.

Also your function needs to return the result. So your function works if you change it to this:

```js
function trocaLetras(conteudoInput) {
    return conteudoInput.replace(/a/g, 'ai')
                        .replace(/e/g, 'enter')
                        .replace(/i/g, 'imes')
                        .replace(/o/g, 'ober')
                        .replace(/u/g, 'ufat');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

two issues here

1. `.replace` doesn't change the original variable value. so if you do

```js
let s = 'some';
s.replace('some', 'else');
console.log(s); // 'some'
```

so your function needs to reassign the value, or you can create a new one.

2. javascript `function` needs explicit returns, so if you don't return anything, it'll show up as undefined.

```js
function trocaLetras(conteudoInput) {
    conteudoInput = conteudoInput.replace(/a/g, 'ai');
    conteudoInput = conteudoInput.replace(/e/g, 'enter');
    conteudoInput = conteudoInput.replace(/i/g, 'imes');
    conteudoInput = conteudoInput.replace(/o/g, 'ober');
    conteudoInput = conteudoInput.replace(/u/g, 'ufat');
    return conteudoInput;
}

const botaoCriptografar = document.getElementById('button');

botaoCriptografar.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var texto = document.querySelector('#texto-para-coleta').value;
    var textoAtualizado = trocaLetras(texto);
    console.log(textoAtualizado);
});
```

```html
<button id='button'>Encrypt</button>

<input id="texto-para-coleta" />
```